# Função de fechar ao clicar fora do elemento

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema no *script* abaixo, a função `myFunction` e `myFunction1` abrem normalmente o *dropdown* ao clicar o botão, mas na parte de clicar fora e fechar, apenas o segundo evento está funcionando.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Fechar ao clicar fora - ESSE NÃO FUNCIONA SE ADICIONAR O DE BAIXO
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Fechar ao clicar fora - ESSE FUNCIONA, MAS O DE CIMA NÃO
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.btn-header')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Porquê você sobrescreve o `window.onclick` quando insere a segunda função. Por quê não trata tudo no mesmo evento?

Comment: Tentei colocar tudo dentro do mesmo evento porém não funcionou do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Tem como mostrar como fez?

Comment: Eu tirei o segundo evento, peguei o IF dele e coloquei junto com o primeiro.

Comment: Então deveria funcionar.

Comment: Voce já tentou colocar console.log(event) dentro do window.onclick = function(event) { para ver se aparece algo no console? ou até mesmo dentro do if para ver se está entrando

Comment: Putz funcionou, estava chamando outro 'show'. Valeu pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas transformando o comentário em resposta. O problema do seu código é atribuir duas vezes o evento `window.onclick`, assim a segunda atribuição sobrescreve a primeira. É semelhante quando você faz `x = 1` e logo depois `x = 2`. O valor de `x` será 2 e o valor 1 será perdido. Para contornar o problema, basta fazer as verificações dentro da mesma função:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {

  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

  if (!event.target.matches('.btn-header')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Desta forma as duas verificações serão executadas no evento `click`.